# ECHOing a variable that contains a string with spaces in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm pretty much a beginner at .bat files, and I've stumbled across something that has stumped me.

```
set /p msg=Enter message here:
echo %msg%>>"D:\\File_location"
```

And then a second file would view it, but I know the viewing file works properly. The issue I am having is whenever the user-set value of `msg`contains spaces, the command prompt returns an error right before it closes itself, and I cannot read the error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above script works for me, assuming I run the Command Prompt as an Admin. Do you have write access to your `D:\`? What about the file named `D:\File_location`?

Comment: Yes. I'm writing this script on my laptop. It works on a standalone script but not on the one I'm writing, oddly. Should I post the script somewhere on here?

Comment: Nevermind! After you posted that this works, I fiddled around with my script and all I had to do was remove all functions attached 'msg'. I was trying to make it to where if you typed exit, it would inform the computer, and that must have caused the problem. Thank you!